# Side reaction arrows: in and out

Tags: arrows, mhchem

I want side arrows coming in and out of the reaction, a ubiquitous convention in biochemistry yet astonishingly not supported by packages like mhchem.

[mychemistry](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/mychemistry/mychemistry_en.pdf) supports it (see p26 of package manual in the link for examples).  Alas mychemistry.sty is not available to me on [QuickLatex](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/) because of its recency.  How can I do this without the aid of mychemistry and without extreme hacking and modifying source code?  I'm not a programmer, and I know nothing about Tex.

I also don't know how to use picture packages like Tikz.  So unless it involves a simple invocation of pre-defined commands, I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: There was an anonymous edit which pointed out that version 3.7.7 of QuickLatex does support mychemistry.  I rejected the edit as that should have been best left as a comment.  As the editor was anonymous, I'm making the comment myself even though I know nothing about it!

Answer (score 3):

The mychemistry package is obsolete since chemfig provides all the functionality now itself. Both mychemistry and chemfig are supported by QuickLaTeX (see [here](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/05/09/chemistry-in-wordpress-using-quicklatex/))

The "in and out" arrows can be achieved by chemfig. This is an example from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart A\arrow{-U>[123][456][][0.25]}B\schemestop
\qquad
\schemestart A\arrow{-U>[123][456][][][90]}B\schemestop
\qquad
\schemestart
 A\arrow{-U>[123][456][][-0.333][-60]}B
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package [`chemarr`](http://ceres.cisc.usp.br/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/chemarr.html) is probably what you're looking for. Also, take a look at [this list](http://ceres.cisc.usp.br/CTAN/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#chem) of chemistry related packages.

Comment: prtcao, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer. This will help others who might have the same problem. You may revoke acceptance if an even better answer comes along. Also, check the FAQ: http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq, “How do I ask questions here?”

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion rberaldo - alas it hasn't quite solved the problem.  It appears though that chemarr only really supports straight arrows.  If only I had enough reputation points to post pictures, but have a look at p26 in the mychemistry link in the original post.  Look out for the bent arrows coming in and out from the sides of the the straight arrows.  Do you or anyone know how I can get this?

Comment: Do you mean, like this one? http://devio.us/~rberaldo/arrow.png The best way is probably using TikZ. It's not as hard as it sounds, though I'm not fluent in it.

Comment: Links seem down, not sure whether those are valid replacements: [chemarr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemarr) and [this list](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#chem)